# Why do the GNU Core Utils have a copyright?

Tags: open-source, gnu

I am very familiar with the notion of "Free Software" especially with the stance of Copyleft that is laid out by Richard Stallman.

However, I find it very confusing that there are copyright statements at the beginning of all of the GNU coreutils?

```
    /* cat -- concatenate files and print on the standard output.
   Copyright (C) 1988-2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
   the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
   (at your option) any later version.
   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
   GNU General Public License for more details.
   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
   along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */
```

This is an excerpt from the [cat.c](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/cat.c) file from the GNU coreutils official repository.
Why would there need to be a Copyright?

It could be my interpretation of Copyright is incomplete. From what I understand, things are Copyrighted to prevent others from copying them, and to protect intellectual property. But the GPL clearly allows all of the above, so whats the point? Surely if the software is truly "Free Software" in Stallman's terms, it would be unnecessary to copyright the software?

Answer (score 0):

From https://choosealicense.com/no-permission/

> When you make a creative work (which includes code), the work is under exclusive copyright by default. Unless you include a license that specifies otherwise, nobody else can copy, distribute, or modify your work without being at risk of take-downs, shake-downs, or litigation. Once the work has other contributors (each a copyright holder), “nobody” starts including you.

Most licenses also have statements about liability and warranty (ie. you can't sue me because my program doesn't work.)

Comment: The GPL is completely permissive though. IIt does specify that anyone can copy, distribute, etc. So whats the point of the copyright?

Comment: `Copyright (C) 1988-2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.` at the start?
It's basically just telling who is giving the right to use the licenced work.